# Python array, unnecessary space

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to read a file and create an array from it. The file is as follows:

```
1 0
0 1
```

The code is:

```
line = file.read()
array = np.fromstring(line.strip(),dtype = bool, sep = " ")
array.resize(2,2)
print array
```

The output is:

```
[[ True False]
 [False  True]]
```

but there is always an extra space before 'True.' Does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: That's just the printing style.

Comment: NumPy does that so things line up nicely. If it didn't, it would have to left-align the output and put the extra spaces at the end, or it would have to simply abandon trying to line things up at all.

Comment: I was considering the extra spaces in the second row because I was wondering if the spaces would cause an error when I processed the array later, but it makes sense that NumPy does that for formatting.

Comment: The spaces won't cause errors. However, note that `print` isn't a good way to serialize an array. Try `print numpy.zeros([1001])` to see why.

Answer (score 1):

You have reproduced the output incorrectly:

```
In [8]: print np.fromstring(line,sep = " ").reshape(2,2).astype("bool")
[[ True False]
 [False  True]]
```

The values are right-aligned for each column.

As an aside, the more numpythonic way of doing this is:

```
In [9]: np.genfromtxt("<name of text file>").astype("bool")
Out[9]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```